# How show values using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new with JavaScript, I have a value in an input field, like 0 or 1 and then when this value changes a word is changed to 'Off' or 'On' respectively.

I know this is pretty simple but I'm new with JavaScript as I said.

*How does your code look like currently? 
What have you tried so far?*

**EDIT**
I'm working in the code right now so nothing great so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(value) {
        if (value == 1)
            return "ON";
        else
            return "OFF";
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" value="1" />
    <p>ON OR OFF RIGHT HERE</p>

</body>
</html>
```

*What difficulties are you encountering?*

I need this values keep been updating all the time, if the value of the input field change the word must change either.

*If you are new to javascript what tutorials/articles/books did you read so far in order to get started?*

Not a specific tutorial right now, I'm googling.

**EDIT 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(){
        toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');
        onoff = document.getElementById('onoff');
        toggler.onChange = function(e){
            onoff.innerHTML = (toggler.value==1)? 'on' : 'off';
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="toggler" value="1" onkeyup="change()" />
    <div id="onoff"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to following the suggestions but still not working, what am I doing wrong here guys ?

Comment: How does your code look like currently? What difficulties are you encountering? What have you tried so far? If you are new to javascript what tutorials/articles/books did you read so far in order to get started?

Comment: As you're new to JS, here are a few questions: What does your HTML look like? Do you want the word to change when the input field value changes? Or when (inside of the input field) a keyboard key is pressed? Or released? Or when the field loses focus? Or ...? (This will determine which event to use...)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I update my post, sorry about the lack of information.

Comment: @ValterHenrique, perfect, now your question is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't posted any code but here it goes some general code:

Your input:

```
<input type='text' id='myinput' onkeyup='contentChanged(this)' />
```

Look for other key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Then, your function:

```
function contentChanged(myinput)
{
    var myvalue = myinput.value;

    if (myvalue == "1")
    {
        // Do something with value = 1
    }
    else if (myvalue == "0")
    {
        // Do something with value = 0
    }
    // And so on...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now that you've posted your code, you can do like as I said:

```
<input type="text" value="1" onkeyup="change(this.value)" />
```

**EDIT 2:**

You're setting two events to your object and `onChange` just works to `select` object. Because of this I suggested you to use `onkeyup` or another key event. Just remove your `onChange` event out of your function.

Change to this and try:

```
function change(){
    toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');
    onoff = document.getElementById('onoff');
    onoff.value = (Number(toggler.value)==1)? 'on' : 'off';
}
```

`Number` function is important to *cast* your input data and be sure that is a number.
Plus add an `maxlength` attribute on your textfield to limit user input data:

```
<input type="text" id="toggler" value="1" onkeyup="change()" maxlength="1" />
```

Comment: although this answer is technically correct, you're adding javascript code inside your markup. If you  declare the handlers inside your javascript code, the content and behaviour are separated. This is called unobtrusive javascript.

Comment: @FrederikCreemers I tried to post an simple answer so he can understand easily.

Comment: although your answer is indeed simpler, teaching people the best practices from the beginning, makes for a better programmer in the end. No offense to your answer btw, it's technically correct.

Comment: @FrederikCreemers thank you, just triyng to pass my little knowledge.

Comment: @Márcio I'm trying to follow your suggestion but is not working, could you please see my code in the post, I updated it.

Comment: @ValterHenrique você é brasileiro pow? Vamo falar em português! :) hahaha

Comment: @Márcio still not working mate as you can see it here :http://jsfiddle.net/mxrXZ/

Comment: @Márcio, rsrsrsrs.
Sou brasileiro sim cara,rs.

Comment: @ValterHenrique cara, eu não tinha visto que você tava tentando mudar o valor de um input, então não se usa `innerHTML` e sim o `value`. Editei o texto, dá uma olhada lá. Aqui no meu firefox o Fiddle deu um erro, mas não era na função era no site mesmo, testei num arquivo aqui na minha máquina e funcionou.

Comment: @Márcio could you please update the code again in the fiddle, in a new one project there, just to separate the things. (I'm speaking english yet, 'cause is the main language here in the stack overflow forum =) )

Comment: @ValterHenrique de nada. dá um votinho aew ;) hahaha t+

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an onChange handler to your input field, this can be done in many ways. for example, let's say your input has an id of #toggler, and the element where either on or off needs to be shown has an id of #onoff

```
toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');
onoff = document.getElementById('onoff');
toggler.onChange = function(e){
    onoff.innerHTML = (toggler.value==1)? 'on' : 'off';
}
```

Comment: Lookup vs conditional: `onoff.innerHTML = [ 'off', 'on'][toggler.value]`

Comment: @Jørgen Thx for the +1, but to make it really unobtrusive, I'd have to put that inside a self executing function, but that'd be outside the scope of this answer. No pun intende :p

Comment: You're right, both about you solution needing modification and the subject being outside the scope :) Nevertheless, it's a lot better than using element attributes.

Comment: Aftere reading the added code in the question, I noticed that what the toggler.value will receive is a string. Therefore, the condition should become `(toggler.value==="1")`. This condition is more precise because it uses the === operator, which does a more strict comparison. In the case mentioned  by @katspaugh, you'd have to convert the value to an int, so that code would look like this: `onoff.value = ['on','off'][Number(toggler.value)]

Comment: Frederik Creemers, quite the opposite. Object property names are *strings*. When you iterate over an array (`for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {}`), index coerces from number to string.

Comment: thx for that. I knew that an object's property names were strings, ad I know that an array's indexes are somehow related to that but never really looked in to how those are internally handled.